# how to deploy smart contract using hardhat via specific signer/owner

Tags: solidity, hardhat, hardhat-deploy

I am trying to deploy a contract as per documentation https://hardhat.org/guides/deploying.html#deploying-your-contracts
Below is how i am deploying it

```
hardhat.config.js

require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers");
require("@openzeppelin/hardhat-upgrades");
const fs = require("fs");
module.exports = {
    defaultNetwork: "hardhat",
    networks: {local: {
        url: "http://127.0.0.1:8545",
        from: "0x46b01b2888929537269342ce9454ca33873e33a9" // want this contract owner
    }},
    solidity: "0.8.1",
};


deploy.js

const { ethers } = require("hardhat");
(async () => {
    try {
        let ContractFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory("SomeContract");
        let contract = await ContractFactory.deploy();
        console.log("Contract address:", contract.address);
        console.log("Contract creation transaction:", contract.deployTransaction.hash);
    }catch(err) {
        console.log('Error deploying contract: ', err);
    }
})();
```

Well, in this way hardhat will deploy contract by using first signer. This is what i dont want... I want to specify a particular Address as singer/owner of the contract.

Is there any way to achieve this other than iterating over all signers() & set the signer i wanted as owner.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Since we have provided `from` address in our hardhat config so we can easily access that address from `network` config & use as contract owner as below.

```
deploy.js

const { network,ethers } = require("hardhat");
(async () => {
    try {
        let ContractFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory("SomeContract");
        let contract_owner = await ethers.getSigner(network.config.from);
        let contract = await ContractFactory.connect(contract_owner).deploy();
        console.log("Contract address:", contract.address);
        console.log("Contract owner:", contract_owner);
        console.log("Contract creation transaction:", contract.deployTransaction.hash);
    }catch(err) {
        console.log('Error deploying contract: ', err);
    }
})();
```

Comment: This is not working! could you check?

Comment: @Russo could you please add more context why it not works. I found this way more feasible as i did not need to expose/write private key for the signers. i can see your solution https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/131563/73114

Answer (score 0):

Where do you keep a private key of your current signer? I have a file `.secret` with the corresponding private key.

If I want other signer, I simply replace the private key inside the `.secret` file.

There are better ways, but this is often the fastest when I am doing some tests, etc.

Comment: i don't want to  use the private key of my address, i believe its not really needed as i am able to deploy contract via my first signer in signers() list so there could be a way to pass my desired address as contract owner.

Comment: In openZeppelin there is an Ownable.sol contact that your own contract could inherit. It also allows you to transfer ownership to any address you might like.

Comment: Thanks Sky. I found a convenient way to do this. Please have a look at answer.

Answer (score 0):

Set accounts

```
localhost: {
      url: "http://127.0.0.1:8545",
      gasPrice: ethers.utils.parseUnits("10", "gwei").toNumber(),
      gas: 7e6,
      accounts: [
        `${DEPLOYER_PRIVATE_KEY_no_0x}`,
        `${USER1PK_no_0x}`
      ],
}
```

Then send some ETH to your deployer address so you can deploy contracts:

```
  const accounts = await ethers.getSigners();
  await accounts[1].sendTransaction({ to: accounts[0], value: toWei(1000) });
  const balance0ETH = await accounts[0].getBalance();
```

But sending ETH is extra work...
if you want to change the default Hardhat accounts:

```
    localhost: {
      url: "http://127.0.0.1:8545",
      gasPrice: ethers.utils.parseUnits("10", "gwei").toNumber(),
      gas: 7e6,
      accounts: {
        mnemonic: "patch alter unable artist hospital prize swear know faith steel frog gesture",
        path: "m/44'/60'/0'/0",
        initialIndex: 0,
        count: 20,
        passphrase: "",
      }
      //accounts: [privateKey1, privateKey2, ...]
      //accounts: { mnemonic: process.env.MNEMONIC_WALLET },
    },
    hardhat: {
      gasPrice: ethers.utils.parseUnits("10", "gwei").toNumber(),
      gas: 7e6,
      accounts: {
        mnemonic: "patch alter unable artist hospital prize swear know faith steel frog gesture",
        path: "m/44'/60'/0'/0",
        initialIndex: 0,
        count: 20,
        passphrase: "",
      }
    },
```

Then run `npx hardhat node` to start your local Ethereum network with those default accounts filled with some ETH balances:

```
Accounts
========
Account #0: 0x6Be02d1d3665660d22FF9624b7BE0551ee1Ac91b (10000 ETH)

Account #1: 0x735113e044BFce4DebA5da7BfBc96A3e6A96F6Da (10000 ETH)

Account #2: 0x314c6751d8fE2d66b886a37F987F695753498b27 (10000 ETH)
...
```